# How to cast and update a numeric value from string column only where applicable

Tags: mysql

MYSQL: Error code 1292 when trying to update a varchar column using cast

I need to update a column from the values of a different varchar column. I want it to populate as 0 when there's a non-integer value like 'N/A' but take the value otherwise. Here's what I've tried so far:

```
update mytable
SET ColumnB =
case when concat('',columnA*1) = columnA
then cast(columnA AS UNSIGNED)
else 0
end
where Row_ID = 1;
```

I want it to populate it as integer values or 0. But instead, I face the below error:
`Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'N/A'`

`Sample columnA values: 1,2,3,N/A,0, ,N/A`
`ColumnB should be: 1,2,3,0,0, ,0`

Table structure, sample values, error on Fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=0719e7bb8d7e2f4b4e13dca40fc09ec9)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use CEIL function, values which contain integer will be converted to integer, values which contain string will be converted to 0

For example:

```
SELECT CEIL('10'); // return 10
SELECT CEIL('N/A'); // return 0
```

The full query will looked like:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET ColumnB = CEIL(columnA)
WHERE Row_ID = 1;
```

If `columnA` has varchar type you must cast it to CHAR. For example:

```
UPDATE mytable
SET columnB = CEIL(CAST(columnA AS CHAR(5)))
WHERE Row_ID = 1;
```

Example in [DBFidle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cc00d781303faac5599ab267a2fce203)

Answer (score 2):

Check This:

> ```
> create table mytable
> (
>   columnA varchar(10),
>   columnB double
> );
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> insert into mytable values ('15.2', null);
> insert into mytable values ('15', null);
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> update mytable
>   SET ColumnB =
>     case when ceil(columnA) = columnA
>     then  ceil(columnA)
>     else 0
>     end
> ```
>
> ```
> ✓
> ```

> ```
> select * from mytable
> ```
>
> ```
> columnA | columnB
> :------ | ------:
> 15.2    |       0
> 15      |      15
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9149b48894e99fe855b4679b80b9757)*

For your data:

```
 update mytable
  SET ColumnB =
    case when REGEXP_LIKE(columnA,'^\\d+(\\.\\d+)?$')
    then  floor(columnA*1)
    else 0
    end
```